# Trying to get property of non-object in json_decode

Tags: php, json

i am new to **JSON** i have a json object retrieved from the database in the form of

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [data] => {"vehicle":[{"year":"2000","make":"Ac","model":"Aceca","acquired_year":"2016","acquired_month":"2","use":"Business","distance_driven_to_work_or_school":"2","distance_driven_manually":"10000"}],"first_name":"ADAS","last_name":"DSADSADA","email":"asddsa@sda.com","phone":"dsasasa","postal_code":"","drivers":[{"name":"ssada","birth_year":"2016","birth_month":"2","birth_day":"2","gender":"female","martial_status":"Single","license_number_provided":"yes","license_number":"asddasdas","license_type":"","training_completed":"","years_been_listed_on_auto_policy_in_north_america":"No Previous Experience","license_suspensions":"","accidents":"Select","convictions":"Select","cancellation_reason":"","cancellation_year":"","cancellation_month":"","cancellation_day":""}],"considering_renters_to_reduce_rate":"yes","install_winter_tires":"no","park_in_private_driveway":"yes","willing_to_install_device":"no","years_insured_with_current_company":"4 Years","how_heard_about_us":"asdaa"}
            [date] => 2017-11-20 18:17:52
            [status] => 0
        )

)
```

now when i try to use json_decode to convert it into an array i am getting **Trying to get property of non-object** here's my code

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($quotes);  //works fine uptil here
    $data = json_decode($quotes->data,true);//the error line
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
?>
```

i tried it a couple of ways but it is not working i tried some other solutions as well stil ending up getting errors any help?

Comment: `json_decode($quotes[0]->data);`

Answer (score 7):

It is because `$quotes` is an array of objects. Try `$quotes[0]->data`, e.g.:

```
$data = json_decode($quotes[0]->data,true);
// ------------------------^^^
```

Comment: @teeyo: Not *another*. The first isn't JSON. The OP is already correctly calling `json_decode` to decode the only JSON in the question, the above is just pointing him/her at how to correctly access the property containing it.

Comment: lol,i wasn't thinking in that dimension i was thinking maybe i did something wrong with json! anyhow thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ah okay, I thought the whole code was a decoded json that returns an array, my bad

Answer (score 2):

You're receiving an array containing objects from the database. You're almost there but instead of

```
$data = json_decode($quotes->data,true);
```

You should use

```
$data = json_decode($quotes[0]->data,true);
```

Comment: @Akintunde: Probably isn't as it just duplicates the previous answer. But they were **right** after one another. (When that happens to me, as it does often, I just delete mine and upvote the other unless I've brought markedly more to the table.)

Comment: Yeah..  It's basically the same answer..  Though I upvoted both of them. Lol